# List form is displaying multiple lines per record

Tags: ms-access

I have a List form, that is supposed to show Sales_Order_Nr, the status of the laybye, customer name etc. However the list form display multiple lines per Sales_Order_Nr. What I want is for the list form to display one line per laybye.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details? Which language / platform are you using? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the table / query feeding the form is correct and showing one line per laybye.

If this is not the case, create a group by query and use it to feed the form.